# SOAPUI Post a XML Request

Tags: xml, rest, soapui

I have a simple Rest based service which mocks a shopping site user creation.
At the /customers endpoint, if we send an xml request, it creates a customer.
I am having a hard time understanding how to send this xml request to this location through SOAPUI : http://localhost:8080/Rest2/rest/customers

Attaching the screenshot of my SOAP UI Project
[image]

As you can see, I typed in the XML request and selected application/xml. But when I hit send, the server responds with the error code which I have set. Also, when I click on the RAW tab, the XML is not attached.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: I can post the server log, but server side is not the problem. I have set the breakpoint which triggers when i send this request but the method responds with a 404 BAD Request, because its not getting the XML request